# How to block Internet for guest account?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, ethernet, guest-session

How can I block or disable my Ethernet Internet connection, for the guest account only?

Comment: Maybe `iptables` with the `owner` match module is an option for you. Never tried it myself though. Here is an example about its use: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.nl/2010/11/how-to-limit-network-access-by-user.html

Answer (score 3):

First you need to edit the network interfaces file.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Now you need to add the simple iptables rule to the interfaces file when the internet connection starts up

Simply add this in the interfaces file

```
pre-up iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP
```

save and exit the file.

Now you need to type in the terminal with the following command

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP
```

and switch users to the username you blocked and try to access the internet.

Comment: The problem with this is that the actual username associated with a guest session starts with `guest-` and then contains random characters; it's different for each guest session, as the user is dynamically created on login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to block particular user:

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP`

Comment: The problem with this is that the actual username associated with a guest session starts with `guest-` and then contains random characters; it's different for each guest session, as the user is dynamically created on login.