# Used iptables to disable internet and now I need to undo it

Tags: networking, internet, iptables

I used iptables to disable access to the internet on one of my user accounts by following [this thread.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145591/how-to-block-internet-for-guest-account?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Since I was only doing it for testing I didn't want it to be permanent. Further web searching taught me that I should have backed up my iptable rule first, but I didn't do that. I just jumped into the command line without even thinking.

I tried searching the web as well as other places in this forum, but only found smarter ways I could have done this.

Any help would be appreciated. If not, I can manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo iptables -F
```

And open:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

then remove the lines that you put there.

Comment: Ha! This worked. I was hoping it wouldn't be too complicated.

Thank you jmunsch!